# Do you have to have your in-app purchase approved in itunesconnect before any testing?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have tried to get this working but keep getting an error that the product id was not found. I created the product but it is still pending developer approval -- is that sufficient or do I need to actually add the screenshot and send for review before it will show up in the product list request.

I tried putting the screenshot and it's been "In Review" for several days now ... I don't want to wait this long before testing if my code works!

Answer (score 0):

user491880

You need to build and test your application before submitting for review.  Get your developer certificate from the provisioning portal, use that to sign the code and test, test, test on the simulator and your device.  Then run a beta program to get others you trust to test, test, test.  And then, and only then, submit for review.